# MathJax rendering in snippets confused by search terms

Tags: bug, mathjax, search

Search terms seem to interfere with MathJax rendering. [Searching for "12 coin"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=12+coin) reveals these post-snippet renderings in the search results:

[image]

Comment: Presumably the same underlying issue as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232124/172958), the tags to handle the formatting are interlaced with the mathjax so the renderer doesn't see it as renderable.